# changing cordova app source (javascript, html, css) without rebuilding

Tags: cordova

How can I modify the contents of /WWW folder (JavaScript, HTML, CSS files) in my CORDOVA app without building the app again?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For developing there is a plugin for that: https://github.com/omefire/cordova-plugin-livereload

Comment: I need a solution for an enterprise app but getting acquainted with this plugin was interesting. Thanku very much.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohammad,
Phonegap has a [developer's App](http://app.phonegap.com/). Develop on your computer, upload immediately (with a build) to your mobile device. It is intended designers. It has some plugin, but not all. It is intended for quick turn around. It is also FREE.

Do NOT use it for full development. It is intended for changing webpages, css and some minor JS changes. Best of Luck